# Excel Addin Automation Run Issue

Tags: vba, excel

**Current Progress:**

I've created an Excel macro to protect/unprotect Workbooks for a customer. Because the macro needs to run every time a workbook is opened, and closed, an Excel add-in seems to be the most feasible. The problem is the way their file structure is designed. The number of excel files this needs handle is about 900. Therefore, a `Workbook_Open()` for each file isn't really feasible.

I went to the Developer tab, selected Excel Add-ins, and then Automation (File -> Options -> Add-ins -> "Excel Add-ins" and Go... -> Automation). I see a list of items but nothing relevant for this add-in from my understanding.

**Questions:**

- Preferably, is there a way to automate this add-in each time a workbook is opened and closed?
- If the add-in must be done manually, how should this be implemented for the users?
- How is the Automation intended to be used? What automation does it provide that I'm not understanding?

**Other Details:**

- The customer has multiple people accessing the files and the files need to be protected for them.

**Solution:**

The solution in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

```
Option Explicit

'Key Variable
Private XLApp As ProtectUnprotect

'Initializing
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New ProtectUnprotect
 End Sub
```

The solution for the `ProtectUnprotect` class module.

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

'Unprotecting Workbook
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Stop
    '-- Code to run here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run on the open of any workbook you need to capture the Application object and attach an event to it.

This example comes from Chip Pearson:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub ProtectUnprotect_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub 

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    ' ---Put your code here---
End Sub
```

To get this working, put the code into a "Class Module" and change the line `Private Sub ProtectUnprotect_Initialize()` to use the name you have given to your Class Module. It must match the module name identically because you are overriding the "_Initialize" method of the module.

When you are done save the Workbook as an Addin. For deployment to a customer I would recommend making an installer that does all the setup steps. Otherwise, deployment to multiple machines will be a poor user experience.

Here is an example of how to make and install an Addin:
https://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm

Comment: First of all, thank you for the direction and help. Unfortunately, the class module isn't working.

Comment: Neither `Stop` paused the code I tried closing and restarting excel:

`Option Explicit

'Global Variables
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Protect_Unprotect_Initialize()
    Stop
    Set App = Application
End Sub

'Unprotecting Workbook
Private Sub App_Workbook_Open(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Stop
end sub`

1) All workbooks were closed before testing.
2) Class name and procedure name match
3) Tested both App_WorkbookOpen and App_Workbook_Open

My assumption is somewhere in `Protect_Unprotect_Initialize` is the issue, but I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: The name of the sub is critical. You added an underscore between workbook and open. You can't do that because `_WorkbookOpen` is a keyword. Never add underscores to sub/function names because it has special meaning to VBA.

Comment: Shouldn't `ProtectUnprotect_Initialize` be the first procedure read in the class?

Comment: Yes. Isn't it? (App is a module level object, module level declarations come before procedures.)

Comment: Well none of the `Stop`s are bringing up the debug window, and the Watches Window says that the `App` Value is <Out of context>.

Comment: Unfortunately the nature of these functions are beyond code. I would have to see your Workbook to help you. Read this: https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-events/

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and insight in this matter.